# MySQLBackup leaves out 'timestamp' column

Tags: mysql, c#

I use MySQLBackup to have a live backup of my MySQL-database. It worked perfectly with MySQL Community Server 5.7. After I upgraded to 8.0 the TIMESTAMP-column simply disappeared in the backup. (There seem to be even a difference between versions 8.0.11 and 8.0.14: Replacing TIMESTAMP by DATETIME and leaving CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value, the backup was still usable in 8.0.11).

I need the timestamp as the database is fed by a Raspberry which doesn’t have the real date/time (not connected to the internet)
 I looked at the export options, but none seem to have to do with the problem.

This is the log file of the backup:

```
-- MySqlBackup.NET 2.0.9.2
-- Dump Time: 2019-02-07 09:22:47
-- --------------------------------------
-- Server version 8.0.14 MySQL Community Server - GPL

-- 
-- Create schema db_1
-- 

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `db_1` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci */;
Use `db_1`;


-- Definition of tab_1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tab_1`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tab_1` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `W_1` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `W_2` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`Time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=66 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table tab_1
-- 

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tab_1` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `tab_1`(`ID`,`W_1`,`W_2`) VALUES          
 (12,2,2),
(13,3,3,),
(14,4,4,);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tab_1` ENABLE KEYS */;


-- Dump completed on 2019-02-07 09:22:48
-- Total time: 0:0:0:0:136 (d:h:m:s:ms)
```

Does anybody know what’s going wrong? I would be very grateful for help!

Comment: *This is the log file of the backup:* This backup file is syntactically incorrect. It is extremely strange.

Comment: Please read the rules about formatting, and correct your post accoring.

Comment: Sorry for the missing poper formatting!

Comment: This is the copy of what I get when I open the backup file either using MySQL Workbench or MS SQL Server Managment Studio 17. I have anonymized the table name and reduced columns. Everything else is what MySQL Backup seems to do. What is incorrect?

Comment: I have tested this at https://www.db-fiddle.com/ with a column of timestamp, it seems to be ok. Please be specific and provide more details to simulate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

.Hi all. I'm the author of this class library `MySqlBackup.NET`.

I had just figured out this was a bug and it was fixed. You may download the new package via Nuget:

Thanks for you support.

For MySql.Data.DLL PM> Install-Package MySqlBackup.NET
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlBackup.NET/

For dotConnector Devart.Express.MySql PM> Install-Package MySqlBackup.Net.DevartExpress
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlBackup.Net.DevartExpress/

For MySqlConnector (MIT) PM> Install-Package MySqlBackup.NET.MySqlConnector
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlBackup.NET.MysqlConnector/

Answer (score 0):

Today I discovered the element that causes MySQLBackup.NET to exclude TIMESTAMP type columns from dumps.

For Date / DateTime / TimeStamp type columns, remove the default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, otherwise these columns will be discarded.

I just did the test with MySQLBackup.NET 2.3.3.1 and MySQL server 8.0.17. No matter what options I placed in my C# code, my TIMESTAMP column did not appear in the dump. After removing the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, the column now appears in the dump.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: This *literally* answered the question...